# Wordpress how to display query results in specific div class if total number of posts is < 2

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a new Wordpress site and am trying to achieve something specific. I'd like to do a query_post and if there is only 1 post available, display that information in a specific div class, otherwise use a different class. Here is a simplified version of the code I am currently using. The one I will end up using, actually has additional query_posts within this:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=events&showposts=-1'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php
    $type = get_field('event_type');
    if( $type && in_array('public', $type) ): ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div id="event" class="public secondary left">
    <?php else: ?>
    <a href="mailto:johnsmith@gmail.com?subject=<?php echo the_field('event_date'); ?> - <?php the_title(); ?> Event Inquiry">
    <div id="event" class="private secondary left">
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <?php
    $type = get_field('event_type');
    if( $type && in_array('public', $type) ): ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div id="event" class="public secondary right">
    <?php else: ?>
    <a href="mailto:johnsmith@gmail.com?subject=<?php echo the_field('event_date'); ?> - <?php the_title(); ?> Event Inquiry">
    <div id="event" class="private secondary right">
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?> 
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I hope this makes sense..

Answer (score 0):

You can check the global query after `query_posts()` like this before you run through the posts and display them:

```
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=events&showposts=-1' );

global $wp_query;
$classes = array( 'secondary' );
if( $wp_query->post_count == 1 ) :
    $classes[] = 'left';
else :
    $classes[] = 'right';
endif; ?>
```

With the above, your code can be shortened to something like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $type = get_field( 'event_type' );
        if ( $type && in_array( 'public', $type ) ) :
            $classes[] = 'public';
            $action = get_permalink();
        else :
            $classes[] = 'private';
            $action = 'mailto:johnsmith@gmail.com';
        endif; ?>

        <!-- Output HTML -->
        <a href="<?php echo $action; ?>">
        <div id="event" class="<?php echo join( ' ', $classes ); ?>">
    <?php endwhile;
endif; ?>
```